# Render new form on show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

models: **entry, comment**

I want to add comments to an entry in my forum on the same page where the entry and all belonging comments are listed.

1. What is the railsway of doing this?
2. How can I render the "new" template of "comments" on my "show" page of "entries"?

   I tried:

   ```
   <% render :template => {:controller => 'comments', :action => 'new'} %>
   ```

   as well as

   ```
   form_for
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #2, try pulling out the new comments form into a partial and then rendering that in both the comments/new view and the entries/show view. So both of those would have a line something like:

```
<%= render :partial => "comments/form" %> # or whatever you named the partial
```

As of the past few Rails releases (I don't remember exactly when this was added), you can just do:

```
<%= render "comments/form" %>
```

I would also ask yourself if there's any reason to have a separate comments/new page in the first place: will it ever make sense to add a comment that's not in the context of some entry?